# Can I use grep matches to execute command?

Tags: grep, rpm

I need to upgrade php from 5.3 to 5.4. I've installed it with rpm.
I want clean install: delete all 5.3 packages, and install all necessary 5.4.
Here is the command to see all installed packages:

```
rpm -qa |grep php
```

It prints out a list of packages, and I want to remove all them with:

```
rpm -e *pakage.name*
```

Can I iterate over all matches in grep results and use each match in:

```
rpm -e *grep.match*
```

Comment: `rpm -qa` does not need `grep` to be invoked. It accepts globbing as in  `rpm qa *php*`. Also use `yum` instead as it will remove / reinstall necessary libraries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
rpm -qa | grep php | xargs rpm -e
```

Answer (score 5):

You generally don't want to remove packages like this in pieces since there's typically dependencies that you're skipping over. Better to do this removal all at once like so:

```
$ rpm -e $(rpm -aq | grep php)
```

Better still I would encourage you to use `yum` to do this vs. RPM.

```
$ yum remove $(rpm -aq | grep php)
```

Even better then these would be to figure out a pattern that matches all the PHP packages and tell YUM to remove based on the pattern . Yes YUM is aware of regular expressions.

```
$ yum remove 'php*'
```

You'll need to make sure that your entire list of packages will fit on the command line but doing this using `xargs` or individually is wrought with problems, if you tell `rpm` to remove 1/2 of the PHP related packages in one command, followed by another `rpm` command with the rest.

Comment: Thaks for explanation! Will try your advice next time. I've alredy removed all and have php5.4 installed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this script:

```
for p in $(rpm -qa |grep php) ; do rpm -e ${p} ; done
```

Comment: @terdon Thanks for the hint, I should really get used replacing those backticks with the $() notation ...

Answer (score 1):

```
( IFS='
' ; printf 'rpm -e "%s"\n' $(rpm -qa |grep php) |
    . /dev/stdin )
```

There you go.